# Assigning KnockoutJS object from $.get

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following code and data

```
{
    "Job": {
        "JobName": null,
        "JobNumber": 13,
        "JobSize": 0,
        "Status": "Finished",
        "DateCreated": "/Date(1312551946280)/"
    },
    "Values": [
        {
            "Id": "8401",
            "Status": "Good",
            "JobNumber": 13
        },
        {
            "Id": "8402",
            "Status": "Bad",
            "JobNumber": 13
        }
    ]
}

function JobViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    self.jobs = ko.observableArray();
    self.selectedJob = ko.observable();
    self.history = ko.observableArray();

    var app = Sammy(function () {
        this.get('#/:jobNumber', function (context) {
            $.get('/home/GetJobInfo/' + context.params.jobNumber, {}, self.selectedJob);
        });

    });

    jQuery(function () {
        app.run();
    });
}
```

I know the $.get is working because I can see the JSON data coming back, and I have used a function in the 3rd parameter on the $.get to see the data.

When I replace that function with self.selectedJob property why is it not being populated?

Thanks

**UPDATE: Here is my HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <link href="~/Content/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Sentinel Web Data</title>
</head>
    <body>
        <div id="sidebar">
            <ul data-bind="foreach: jobs">
                <li><a data-bind="text: $data.JobName, attr: { href: '#/' + $data.JobNumber}"></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="job">
            <span data-bind="text: JobNumber"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="history"  data-bind="with: history"></div>
        <script src="~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.1.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/sammy-0.7.4.min.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/JobViewModel.js"></script>
        <script>
            ko.applyBindings(new JobViewModel());
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

When looking at the get in the console and having a watch on self.selectedJob.Job I get "undefined"

Comment: Can you post your HTML? And also the JS part where do you call `ko.applyBindings`?

Comment: @nemesv Updated with HTML

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the console, you are looking at it incorrectly. To see the selected job name, you need to use:

```
var vm = new JobViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

Then in the console:

```
vm.selectedJob().Job
```

As for the binding to the html, you're not binding to the selected job:

```
<div id="job" data-bind="with: selectedJob">
    <span data-bind="text: JobNumber"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Why does it work in this demo? There is no mapping plugin - http://learn.knockoutjs.com/WebmailExampleStandalone.html

Comment: Good point! I must admit, I have no idea that you could do that. I'll have a think about what's happening then.

Comment: It should just populate the observable with the data object from the JSON call. What makes you think that it isn't working? If you could post the html, that might help.

Comment: Done! But also in a console I can do self.selectedJob.Job.JobNumber and I get undefined

Comment: I've put the bindings in my already existing jQuery ready function and that breaks it completely

Comment: What do you mean by breaks completely? In your original code, is the binding call happening before the json call? Can you put up a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: It is but I dont believe that has anything to do with it. Its exactly the same for the webmail demo

Comment: Well, there is one important difference, the demo works! They have the rest of their script files loading at the top of the html, rather than at the bottom, which is what made me think that it's a timing issue. They don't assign the Sammy app to a variable and run it on load, so why don't you try copying that part of the demo too?

Comment: Have you added the binding code to the html? Ignore the console for now, just see if you can get it to bind in the html. I've updated the console stuff too, as the console won't have access to your vm, as you don't store it in a variable anywhere.

Comment: I've got it working by adding the "with" binding and amending the GET to $.get('/home/GetJobInfo/' + context.params.jobNumber, {}, function (data) {
                self.selectedJob(data);
            });

Comment: Not sure why your original way of populating it didn't work, but that is how I always do the population. Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to get this working by doing this however I am unsure why my original code did not work:

```
$.get('/home/GetJobInfo/' + context.params.jobNumber, {}, function (data) {
    self.selectedJob(data);
});
```